# Model that is used in several modules. Where should it be located?

Tags: zend-framework

I am developing a ZF1 + Doctrine2 app that has two modules: default which is a default standard web site and 'rest' which provides REST interface. Quite obviously, both modules use the same models because they share many common DB operations. The goal of my architecture is to avoid calling Doctrine EM methods from the controller, create abstraction layer on top of it (sort of API) for decoupling and code consistency (personally I don't like sometimes calling models, sometimes building queries in the controller but I may be wrong).

I was tempted to put the models in library (/library//Users/Users.php and etc) but not sure if library is appropriate here just because models are meant to be in application folder, they do not extend any ZF classes. But library is a shared between the whole application and that made me consider it.

Other option I came up with is to put it in application/modules/default/models but if I do that, it logically separates from other modules although those models are global.

Which solution is better in this case or are there any other ways I didn't mention to do it properly?

Comment: in my opinion a module should be 100% "self-sufficient" or modular. meaning , it should only require the library and whatever custom class you defined. the goal is to be able to port an module from application to application , like a "plugin" , so i dont think it is "UN-DRY" to have the same models in the default app and the module. cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to keep my library folder for cross-project stuff, a kind of vendor folder for libs that I drop in and either use directly or extend in my own classes (adding autoloadernamespaces entries, as required).

In a multi-module application, I keep cross-module stuff - like a common models, mappers, view helpers, and partial scripts that will be used by all modules - at application-level, named with the appnamespace (`Application_` or `My_` or some such thing). Then, I push all modules - including the default module! - into `modules` folder. Module-specific stuff - like controllers, forms, views - are then namespaced with the module name. Something like:

```
/application
    /configs
        application.ini
    /layouts
    /models # app-level!
    /modules
        /admin
            /controllers
            /forms
            /models
            /views
                /helpers
                /scripts
        /front
            /controllers
            /forms
            /models
            /views
                /helpers
                /scripts
    /views  # app-level!
        /helpers
        /scripts    
/data
    /cache
/library
    /App
    /Zend
/public
    index.php
    /assets
        /css
        /img
        /js
/scripts
```

Typically, the module bootstrap classes - extending `Zend_Application_Module_Boostrap` - registers the correct resource autoloader mappings to make object instantiation a breeze.

One note: Since I prefer that my controllers employ the module namespace  in which they reside, I need to set a param on the frontcontroller to make him aware of that:

```
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = true
```

tl:dr:

- Cross-project classes reside in `library` and employ their own lib namespace.
- App-level, cross-module classes reside at app-level and employ the appnamespace
- Module-level classes reside in a module folder and employ the module namespace

Answer (score 1):

ZF 1.x is not really modular and I think modules in ZF 1.x are a bit of a misnomer. They are more like domain libraries in my opinion. With that being said,
I look at code separation like this (pure opinion).

- Any code that I expect to be reused or reusable in another project I put in the library. eg. View helpers, action helpers, abstract model classes, base models, plugins etc...
- Any code that is application specific and will be used universally in the app I put in the application level directories. This is stuff like concrete data mappers, DbTable Models (I don't use Doctrine), forms and layouts...
- Any code that belongs specifically to a module(domain) and will not or cannot be used anywhere else I put in module level directories. This includes  stuff like special view and action helpers, one of forms, and mostly it's where I put my domain(entity) models.

To illustrate this I'll present an example (personal namespace omitted):

I have a module named *music* in my application, this module has a database table named *'music'*.
so these are the files I might have to use this Db table in my module.

```
//The DbTable model
application
    /models
        /DbTable
            /Music.php //extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
```

To use that DbTable model I build a mapper that uses 2 files

```
//Base mapper class
library
    /Application
        /Model
            /Mapper.php
//The concrete mapper
application
    /modules
        /models
            /MusicMapper.php //extends Namespace_Application_Model_Mapper
```

and to use that mapper I would have a domain model which is made up of 2 files, a base entity class and concrete entity class.

```
//Base entity class
library
    /Application
        /Model
            /Entity.php

//and the concrete entity class
application
    /modules
        /models
            /Music.php //extends Namespace_Application_Model_Entity
```

I feel that organizing my files and classes this way keeps the code as DRY as possible without getting too confusing and scattered.

I hope this helps.